# what iOS version do i have on my Mac

Tags: iphone, ios

How can I know exactly what version is the iOS in my Mac?

Comment: You want to ask this on http://apple.stackexchange.com/  Also, if you click the apple in the top-left corner it'll give you some kind of "about this mac" option that you can use to find out what version of OS X you're running. Note that your Mac doesn't run iOS.

Comment: You have whatever version came with the Xcode tools you downloaded. When in doubt, go download the latest from developer.apple.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Mac does not run iOS. Do you mean the iOS simulator? The iOS SDK perhaps? These are all very different concepts.

Comment: Hi, actually yes i do mean the iOS SDK version, how can i know what version i use please ??

Comment: It doesn't come with any SDK. You have to install one. So it's whatever version you installed.

Comment: ok, let me ask you other way, i gonna buy a book, so should it be iPhone 4 Development or iPhone 3 Development??